# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method camera#animate on channel plugins.flutter.dev/google_maps_android_0)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I have a problem. I have seen and tried many things from here. However, I did not get any results.
I'm getting the error

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method camera#animate on channel plugins.flutter.dev/google_maps_android_0).
```

The place where 0 is in google_maps_andrioid_0, for example, becomes 1 and increases each time.

Can you help me?

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved this problem. I wanted to share the solution with you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58391946/19929536